# Regenerating array key for wp_schedule_event args

Tags: wp-cron

I've been working on this the last day with no luck. Is there any way to update a stored args array key for an event scheduled? Reason I ask is I have array args that look like this when scheduling a payment:

```
Array
(
    [customer] => Array
        (
            [name] => ''
            [email] => ''
            [id] => ''
            [user_id] => ''
            [street] => ''
            [city] => ''
            [state] => ''
            [zip] => ''
            [phone] => ''
        )

    [payments] => Array
        (
        )

    [recurring] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 70
            [amount] => 1600
        )

)
```

Payments will get pushed to that array as they are processed, thus changing the array and changing how the key will be serialized. Is it possible to update the key of the array with the new serialized args?

Answer (score 0):

So what I came up with, which seems to work is the following:

This function will search by the user id and find the corresponding cron job

```
function search_user_cron( $hook, $user_id ) {

    $crons = _get_cron_array();

    foreach( $crons as $timestamp => $cron ) 

        if( isset( $cron[$hook] ) ) 

            foreach( $cron as $jobs ) 

                foreach( $jobs as $key => $job ) 

                    if( $job['args'][0]['customer']['user_id'] == $user_id )

                        return array( 'id' => $user_id, 'timestamp' => $timestamp, 'key' => $key );

}
```

Then I use this function to go through and create a new job with the new args and unset the old one

```
function replace_cron_args( $hook, $user_id ) {

    // lets find the cron job corresponding to the user id
    $user = search_user_cron( $hook, $user_id );

    // get all the current cron jobs
    $crons = _get_cron_array();

    // get the most recent updated arguments
    $stored_args = get_user_meta( $user['id'], 'oe_customer_details', true );

    // get the current user key
    $key = $user['key'];

    // get the current user timestamp
    $timestamp = $user['timestamp'];

    // serialize the new arguments
    $newkey = md5( serialize( $stored_args ) );

    // update the stored arguments
    $crons[$timestamp][$hook][$key]['args'][0] = $stored_args;

    // replace the key with the new serialized key
    $crons[$timestamp][$hook][$newkey] = $crons[$timestamp][$hook][$key];

    // unset the old array
    unset( $crons[$timestamp][$hook][$key] );

    // set the new cron jobs
    _set_cron_array( $crons );

}
```

If anyone can think of a more efficient way, please let me know.